# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (4200,) and (16800, 1)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

Ihave created an SVR model using SCIKIT-LEARN, I am trying to plot my data but for some reason I am receiving the error:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes
>   (4200,) and (16800, 1)

I have split my data into training and testing data, training the model and making a prediction. My code is:

```
X_feature = wind_speed

X_feature = X_feature.reshape(-1, 1)## Reshaping array to be 1D from 2D

y_label = Power
y_label = y_label.reshape(-1,1)

    timeseries_split = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3) ## Splitting training testing data into 3 splits
    for train_index, test_index in timeseries_split.split(X_feature):## for loop to obtain print the training and splitting of the data 
    print("Training data:",train_index, "Testing data test:", test_index)#
    X_train, X_test = X_feature[train_index], X_feature[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y_label[train_index], y_label [test_index]



    timeseries_split = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3) ## Splitting training testing data into 3 splits






    scaler =pre.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1)).fit(X_train)## Data is being preprocessed then standard deviation 


    scaled_wind_speed_train = scaler.transform(X_train)## Wind speed training data is being scaled and then transformed 

    scaled_wind_speed_test = scaler.transform(X_test)## Wind speed test data is being scaled and then transformed

    SVR_model = svm.SVR(kernel='rbf',C=100,gamma=.001).fit(scaled_wind_speed_train,y_train)



    y_prediction = SVR_model.predict(scaled_wind_speed_test)

    SVR_model.score(scaled_wind_speed_test,y_test)


    rmse=numpy.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_label,y_prediction))
    print("RMSE:",rmse)


    fig, bx = plt.subplots(figsize=(19,8))
    bx.plot(y_prediction, X_feature,'bs')
    fig.suptitle('Wind Power Prediction v Wind Speed', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Wind Power Data')
    plt.ylabel('Predicted Power')
    plt.xticks(rotation=30)
    plt.show() 


     fig, bx = plt.subplots(figsize=(19,8))
     bx.plot( y_prediction, y_label)
     fig.suptitle('Wind Power Prediction v Measured Wind Power ', fontsize=20)
     plt.xlabel('Wind Power Data')
     plt.ylabel('Predicted Power')


     fig, bx = plt.subplots(figsize=(19,8))
     bx.plot(y_prediction)
     fig.suptitle('Wind Power Prediction v Measured Wind Power ', fontsize=20)
     plt.xlabel('Wind Power Data')
     plt.ylabel('Predicted Power')
```

I believe this code is being genrated when I am trying to obtain the rmse in the line:

```
rmse=numpy.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_label,y_prediction))
```

This error also occurs when I comment this line out and try to plot my data..

> My traceback error message is:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-ed11a9ca7fd8> in <module>()
     79 
     80     fig, bx = plt.subplots(figsize=(19,8))
---> 81     bx.plot( y_prediction, y_label)
     82     fig.suptitle('Wind Power Prediction v Measured Wind Power ', fontsize=20)
     83     plt.xlabel('Wind Power Data')

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1715                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1716                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1717             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1718         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1719         if pre_doc is None:

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1370         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, _alias_map)
   1371 
-> 1372         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   1373             self.add_line(line)
   1374             lines.append(line)

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    402                 this += args[0],
    403                 args = args[1:]
--> 404             for seg in self._plot_args(this, kwargs):
    405                 yield seg
    406 

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    382             x, y = index_of(tup[-1])
    383 
--> 384         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    385 
    386         if self.command == 'plot':

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    241         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
    242             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension, but "
--> 243                              "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
    244         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    245             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have "

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (4200,) and (16800, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have mixed the arguements for `mean_squared_error`, it should be

```
rmse=numpy.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_prediction))
```

**Update** : as per the latest error, try this

```
fig, bx = plt.subplots(figsize=(19,8))
bx.plot(y_prediction, scaled_wind_speed_test,'bs')
fig.suptitle('Wind Power Prediction v Wind Speed', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Wind Power Data')
plt.ylabel('Predicted Power')
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.show()
```

**Update 2**
In case you get error on the other plot try this

```
fig, bx = plt.subplots(figsize=(19,8))
bx.plot( y_prediction, y_test)
fig.suptitle('Wind Power Prediction v Measured Wind Power ', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Wind Power Data')
plt.ylabel('Predicted Power')
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't realise that error, Thank you. But I am getting a new error " ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (4200,) and (16800, 1)" along with a blank graph. I have updated by question with the rew traceback error.

Comment: That would be the same principle. You need to generate your y_prediction using your x_test, then you should have the same size. Also, you may need to do `mean_squared_error(y_test, y_prediction[0])` to get it to work.

Comment: Also  try `mean_squared_error( scaler.transform(y_test), y_prediction[0])`

Comment: The error Trace is still same as earlier in your question

Comment: @levraininjaneer Hi, when I try that line of code that you suggested I get the error code "TypeError: Singleton array 0.1853680535764517 cannot be considered a valid collection." any ideas what this could be?

Comment: maybe try `mean_squared_error( scaler.transform(y_test), y_prediction)`

Comment: @MohammedKashif The traceback error on my question posted is the updated version, that being the one after your rmse suggestion. Thank you

Comment: @levraininjaneer Sorry but that code returned back the original error message of "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (4200,) and (16800, 1)"

Comment: OK. I think you understand that the sizes must be the same. The (16800, 1) means it is a 2-D array, but with just one column. To get it to a 1D array, like the other one, you can do `<your_array_name>.transpose()[0]`.

Now you need to make sure the two arrays have the same amount of elements. I suspect the reason why they are not is because `y_prediction` is generated from `x_test`, but in-between it goes through the `scalar`, which might change its length. So you must take the equivalent scaling action with your `y_test` before you can do the mean squared.

Comment: @levraininjaneer I hope it is ok to ask but, would it be possible to have an example code to help resolve this?

Comment: @MohammedKashif Was the whole trace back error of any use? As I still confused. Regards

Comment: @Asif.Khan sorry I was viewing on my mobile app and it was not showing the updated error trace :-) Yes, your stack trace did help in identifying the culprit :D

Comment: @MohammedKashif Thank you! You have helped to obtain the first and final plot!!  However, for the plot "   fig, bx = plt.subplots(figsize=(19,8))
    bx.plot( y_prediction, y_label)
    fig.suptitle('Wind Power Prediction v Measured Wind Power ', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Wind Power Data')
    plt.ylabel('Predicted Power')". When i try to plot this I get the error "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (4200,) and (16800, 1)". Any idea on how I could resolve this? I have updated the traceback error message. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Numpy's function `mean_squared_error` expects two arrays of the same size.
The error you are getting implies that these two do not have the same size.

You can check your array sizes by

```
print(array_1.shape)
print(array_2.shape)
```

if the output you get is

```
output:
> (4200,)
> (4200, 1)
```

you can fix by doing

```
new_array_2 = array_2.transpose()[0]
```

and then

```
mean_squared_error(array_1, new_array_2)
```

if the two input arguments, whatever they are give you the following shapes

```
print(array_1.shape)
print(array_2.shape)

output:
> (4200,)
> (16800, 1)
```

try

```
new_array_1 = scalar.transform(array_1)
```

or

```
new_array_2 = scalar.transform(array_2)
```

until you get arrays with the same number whether it's 16800 or 4200.
Once you have two of the same size, but the one or both still comes with an extra dimension,

then again do

```
new_new_array_1 = scalar.transform(new_array_1)[0]
```

and feed these to `mean_squared_error`, e.g.

```
mean_squared_error(new_new_array_1, new_array_2)
```

Comment: I have checked the shape sizes, he shape sizes are: shape1: (4200, 1)
(4200,)

Comment: that's great news. then just add a `[0]` after the first argument, and you should be in business, i.e. `mean_squared_error(y_test[0], y_prediction)`

Comment: I think we nearly be at a solution. I have placed a zero but now I got the error message "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 4200]"

Comment: OK, in that case is may work to do `mean_squared_error(y_test.transpose()[0], y_prediction)`

Comment: I have used "new_array_2 = array_2.transpose()[0]" to change the shapes of my data but I still get "shape1: (4200, 1)
shape1: (4200,)". I have then tried to do "new_new_array_1 = scalar.transform(new_array_1)[0]" as  y_test = scaler.transform(y_test)[0] but I am still getting " Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 4200]"

Comment: what do you get when you say `print(new_new_array.shape)` ? and what do you get when say `print(scalar.transform(y_test).shape)` ?